# Shibboleth IDP 3 with PHP authentication

Tags: php, mysql, saml-2.0, shibboleth, simplesamlphp

I have installed Shibboleth IDP 3 on one of our server and Shibboleth SP on another server.Is it possible to use **php** to send attributes to Shibboleth SP for login authentication?